# Django 1.5 url redirect with regex?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='^(?P<username>\w+)/$')),
```

but it doesn't seem to parse the regex part to the actual username...

I've done research but I can only find examples that redirect to exact urls or other regex examples that work but only in Django 1.1

Anyone have any idea how to do this in Django 1.5+?

Comment: What would this do exactly?

Comment: `RedirectView.as_view()` wasn't available until Django 1.3. Where did you get the impression that it would take a regular expression? It does take a *template* string as a URL, but a regular expression was never in the books.

Comment: What do you expect to do here? Redirect `/`, to `/<username>` perhaps?

Comment: I take it you read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)?

Comment: `urls.py` is not a substitute for `mod_rewrite`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to redirect myapp/ to myapp/username basically.
I know RedirectView.as_view() wasn't available in 1.1 but I just mentioned that there had been examples of url redirects that took regex in say 1.1 but I can't seem to find a similar solution for 1.5

Comment: I don't need to tinker with mod_rewrite...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `RedirectView`, and override the `get_redirect_view` method.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class UserRedirectView(RedirectView):

    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        # it would be better to use reverse here
        return '/myapp/%s/' % self.request.user.username
```

You would include your `UserRedirectView` in your `myapp.urls.py` module as follows:

```
url(r'^$', UserRedirectView.as_view(), name='myapp_index'),
```

It would be better to [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) the url instead of hardcoding `/myapp/` in the url above. As an example, if you were redirecting to a url pattern like the following

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'myapp.view_user', name='myapp_view_user'),
```

Then you could change the `get_redirect_url` view to:

```
    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        return reverse('myapp_view_user', args=(self.request.user.username,))
```

Comment: Amazing! This worked perfectly! I'm gonna do some research now on return vs reverse.

Comment: I've added an example of how to use `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this

```
(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'your_view'),
```

where `your_view` is

```
def page(request, username):
    pass
```

If you need redirection with parameters, you can use

```
('^(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to',
 {'url': '/bar/%(username)s/'}),
```

More info here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to
and here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls

Comment: i think this approach is better as explained in framework docs than the hack on every class/function. But its a creative solution @Alasdair

Comment: @cool_n_curious Subclassing `RedirectView` isn't a hack, it's an approach that's used [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview). The `redirect_to` is fine if the username is in the url, but in the original question, the op needs to get the username from the request, not the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package https://github.com/maykinmedia/django-regex-redirects. It is used in some of our projects